# What is the best way playing MOV file?

Tags: ios

I have generated that MOV file from the screen shots of the UI and record the sound. Combined both video and audio and generate a MOV formatted movie.

I have seen quite a lot of MPMoviePlayerViewController sample but it just shows me black screen. I tried AVPlayer but I can't get it work.

I'm new to playing movie file in iOS, please help.

Here is my code:

```
NSString  *fileNamePath = mVideo;
NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *oldappSettingsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNamePath];
NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:oldappSettingsPath];
self.mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:path];

self.mPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
self.mPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
self.mPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[[self.mPlayer view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:[self.mPlayer view]];
[self.mPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.mPlayer play];
```

Comment: Please add any code related to the issue. Even the MPMoviePlayerViewController black screen code

Comment: ok, thanks for the comment. here is the code with MPMoviePlayerViewController black screen code @MidhunMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the fixed to my `MPMoviePlayerController` :

```
         NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:oldappSettingsPath];
         if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:oldappSettingsPath]) {
             NSLog(@"Exist");
             self.mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:path];
             self.mPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
             self.mPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
             self.mPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
             self.mPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
             [[self.mPlayer view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
             [self.view addSubview:[self.mPlayer view]];
             [self.mPlayer prepareToPlay];
             [self.mPlayer play];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Don't Exist");
         }
```

I added also:

```
        self.mPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
```

in my case the player shows black screen since the file i played is not there, so i added a checking first if the file exist or not.